# make a variable final in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

When I try to make the variable A(String) equal to e(Which comes from a Plain Text)
this appears in the line of the error(In the code below):

```
Variable 'e' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.
```

I don't know how to make 'e' final.

```
public void MORSE(View v)
    {

        EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        TextView T=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.translation);
        Button TRAD=(Button) findViewById(R.id.translate);
        TRAD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View view){

        String A;
        A=""+e;                        //HERE IS THE ERROR.

  }
});
}
```

Comment: e is your `View` it is not text. use e.getText()

Comment: `final EditText e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a string to an EditText:

```
 A=""+e;
```

This can't be done.
You probably want to add a string to a string, instead:

```
 A = "" + e.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign e to a, since e is an edittext while a is a String. This is a java problem, and I recommend you learning java from thenewboston's tutorials before getting into android.
Anyway, you need to use

```
A = e.getText();
```

No need for final variables, which use the final keyword.

Using a final keyword here, would cause problems. A final variable can't be edited, and won't be a solution since the variable will hold a text representation of that EditText, not it's actual text. Just for the sake of completeness, though, a final variable is represented like this:

```
final String finalString = "This string will now for ever hold this value. This can't be changed.";
```