# Android/Java - Clicking a image in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

I made a listview in Android Studio. The listview has a image in every item but I don't know how to make it clickable. I did browse the internet for a solution but the hard part seems to be implementing it in my own code. I cannot figure that out.

Image in question = ex_img

-- Keep in mind when the image is clicked, it should also know its position in the list.

Thanks for reading and I hope you can help me out.

Adapter for list:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private String[] ex_name;
    private String[] ex_diff;
    private String[] ex_muscle;
    private String[] ex_dpr;
    private Integer[] ex_img;
    private Activity context;

    public CustomList(Activity context, String[] ex_name, String[] ex_diff, String[] ex_muscle, String[] ex_dpr,
                      Integer[] ex_img) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, ex_name);
        this.context = context;
        this.ex_name = ex_name;
        this.ex_muscle = ex_muscle;
        this.ex_diff = ex_diff;
        this.ex_dpr = ex_dpr;
        this.ex_img = ex_img;

    }
//LIST --> XML
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, true);
        TextView list_name = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.ex_name);
        TextView list_diff = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.ex_diff);
        TextView list_muscle = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.ex_muscle);
        ImageView list_image = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.ex_img);
        TextView list_dpr = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.ex_dpr);

        list_name.setText(ex_name[position]);
        list_muscle.setText(ex_muscle[position]);
        list_diff.setText(ex_diff[position]);
        list_dpr.setText(ex_dpr[position]);
        list_image.setImageResource(ex_img[position]);

        return  listViewItem;

    }
}
```

Part from MainActivity that might be needed:

```
 private Integer img[] = {
            R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_location_on_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_update_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_local_dining_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_local_dining_white_24dp

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomList customList = new CustomList(this, name, diff, muscle, dpr, img);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(customList);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You Clicked "+name[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You already implemented `OnItemClickListener`. You have position in that. When any list item view is clicked `onItemClick ` will be invoked.

Comment: So that's a bad thing when I want a overlapping one when clicking exactly on the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onClickListener` to your `ImageView` in `getView()` -

```
list_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Here you have the position too.
});
```

Just make the `position` parameter `final` in `getView()`

Comment: I heard making it final is a bad thing though. This is actually the code I already had for it. Thanks for clearing it up though. Trying it out now!

Comment: Making it final is a good practice. Send me a link where you found that info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144663/make-a-variable-final-in-android-studio

Comment: If you would have read the post carefully then you would have known  that the post is not saying that `final` is bad. It's just that you cannot change the value assigned to final variable  which will not create any problem in your case  because you don't want to and you should not change the value stored in `position`.